# Is it possible to mock a library?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

After dozens of research on the subject and a lot of thinking, I leave it to you in this new question:
Is it possible to mock an entire library with Python? I would like the import of this library and all its packages / modules / etc to be done without having to define each element by hand, with mock and sys.module ... :(

In my case, I use a library specific to the job and I would like to be able to work on my code at home, without having to recode my imports, on code which is not dependent on this library.

Example:

```py
"""Main file.

I define the mock here.
"""

mocked = MagicLibraryMock("mylib")  # the dream
```

```py
"""File with lib imports.

I can import anything and use it as a mock.
"""

import mylib
from mylib.a import b
from mylib.z import c
from mylib.a.e.r import x

foo = x()
bar = c.a.e.r.t.d()
bar.side_effect = [1, 2, 3]
bar()
```

Comment: It depends on how much functionality you actually want from the library. I haven't done this exactly, but if you want something along the lines of "print the name of the function when it's called and never return anything" I can think of a fairly straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @saffronsnail - the library being very complex and very large, with a lot of imports from my application, I will really need a simple functionality which allows me to "mock imports" from this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to integrate a class inherited from a dictionary to overload the `__getitem__` method of `sys.modules`. But the problem is that the import method also uses `__iter__`, and there it becomes much more complicated to return a `MagicMock` according to the result, knowing *that it is not recommended to directly modify the import source code* - [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py).

Finally I lose less time extracting imports from my application to sub-modules which will take care of solving them. I can thus intercept these imports more easily without dirtying my code.
The design is more interesting.

Thanks for your help.